# Azure Devops clone This is not a valid source path in source tree

Tags: azure-devops, atlassian-sourcetree

I have managed to finally add my devops account in sourcetree using the https://orgname.visualstudio.com path

Now I am having issues cloning the repository

I am using the path that devops gives me

> https://orgname@dev.azure.com/orgname/MyProject/_git/MyRepo

but I get an error saying

> This is not a valid source

The details reveal authentication issues... Yet it authenticated fine when adding the account.

What is going on? Does the azure account have to be the default account?

Comment: May I know what's the status of this? Can you succeed to use the azure devops URL in sourcetree now?

Comment: Tried all the solutions below - nothing works. Switched to GitHub desktop using the same machine, same repo, same credential - works. Tried VSCode source control, all same - works. Interesting.

Answer (score 10):

I managed to fix this by changing from the sourcetree embedded git to my system git Tools>Options>Git>Git Version>Select System. Afterwards when trying again it prompted me to login on my organization domain with 2 factor as if logging in on the devops web app directly.

My system Git is using manager-core for the credential management which is probably not the same system which the embedded version used.

Answer (score 5):

I tried the above solutions (and more) but for me what in the end solved the problem was that the git-password I first wrongly entered when I tried to access the repo had been saved in **Keychain** (MacOS) and when I tried again this password was used without giving me the option to type it in again. I deleted the password to the Azure DevOps project in Keychain and then got prompted to enter the password again whereafter I pasted the **Personal Access Token (!!)** generated in Azure Devops and it finally worked!

Comment: This worked for me too. Ended up having to enter my PAT twice, both of which got saved to the Keychain.

Answer (score 4):

It could happen when you entered wrong credentials and you don't get asked again, try this:

1. *Go to : Sourtree->Settings->Advance (tab)*
2. *Under: "Default usernames for URLs which do not include one:" delete your wrong credentials.*
3. *Try accessing your repo again with right credentials.*

Comment: Where is the Preferences menu?

Comment: Thanks for the detail @Spacez! I've updated the menu option with "Settings"

Answer (score 2):

This is not the issue which caused by Azure devops. No matter `https://xxx.visualstudio.com`, or the URL which like `dev.azure.com`, they should all available git source.

For me, I just try with multi different git URLs, and found the few of URLs are failed with same error with you. But it prompt `This is a git repository` after I exit the SourceTree and re-configure the clone with same URL which encountered the error previously.

[image]

This seems be the most common Sourcetree problem which encountered by many users, not just the URL of azure devops that you occurred.

Check this [thread](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/quot-This-is-not-a-valid-source-path-URL-quot-when-connecting/qaq-p/165949), and try with its recommend way:

> Open source tree, Tools -> Options -> Click on Git Tab -> Update
>   Embedded Git.

Or, consider the method I used: **exit** the Sourcetree, and **re-configure** the clone with same URL. *(Not recommend since this can not permanently solve this issue)*

Answer (score 0):

If your organisation has 2FA enabled in Azure Devops, Sourcetree on Mac's default git credentials management isn't sufficient. However, installing `git-credential-manager` will allow use of system dialog and keychain and allow for the 2FA to work. Install GCM via `brew install --cask git-credential-manager`, then check out the repo using the full URL of the form `https://myorgname@dev.azure.com/iqxr/ProjectName/_git/RepoName` (replacing myorgname, ProjectName and RepoName with the values for you).

You should then be prompted in your system web browser to log in etc.